# Is there any way to control the concatenation of the blockproc output?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, dct

This is a follow up to the question: [Overlapping sliding window over an image using blockproc or im2col?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040688/overlapping-sliding-window-over-an-image-using-blockproc-or-im2col/)

So by using the code :

```
B = blockproc(A, [1 1], @block_fun, 'BorderSize', [2 2], 'TrimBorder', false, 'PadPartialBlocks', true)
```

I was able to create an overlapping sliding window over my image and calculate the `dct2` for each window. But the problem is that `blockproc` concatenates the output in a way that I cannot use. The output greatly depends on the block size and the size of the output matrix is different because of it every time.

My `dct2` function creates a `1 x 200` vector for every block or window. So I assumed that if there are 64 blocks I should get something like `64 x 200` or `200 x 64` output, but I get something like `64 x 1600` or in case of larger blocks I get `15 x 400`.

Looking into the `blockproc` function the problem is caused by

```
% write 4 corner blocks
b(1:ul_output_size(1),1:ul_output_size(2),:) = ul_output;
if ll_processed
    last_row_start = final_rows - size(ll_output,1) + 1;
    last_row_width = size(ll_output,2);
    b(last_row_start:end,1:last_row_width,:) = ll_output;
end
if ur_processed
    last_col_start = final_cols - size(ur_output,2) + 1;
    last_col_height = size(ur_output,1);
    b(1:last_col_height,last_col_start:end,:) = ur_output;
end
if lr_processed
    last_row_start = final_rows - size(ll_output,1) + 1;
    last_col_start = final_cols - size(ur_output,2) + 1;
    b(last_row_start:end,last_col_start:end,:) = lr_output;
end
```

Apparently, blockproc further divides the blocks into upper left, upper right, lower left and lower right and concatenates that result. And that is why I am getting all this mixed outputs.

I need the output of each block in its each row, for each window. Each window should just give me a `1x200` output, that I can feed into my classifier.

Can I force the output of `blockproc` in the way that I want it, just give the output of each block.

If not, I would really appreciate an alternative solution to have an overlapping sliding window over the image.

**edit:** would it be possible to save the blocks data using `block_struct.data` for every block into a cell array inside the function `block_fun` and then use that array to extract my features?

Thank you

**edit:**

```
B = blockproc(images_m{1}, [64 64], @(x)reshape(x.data(:),[1 1 numel(x.data)]), 'BorderSize', [10 10], 'TrimBorder', false, 'PadPartialBlocks', true, 'PadMethod', 'replicate');
imgs = {};
for i = 1:size(B,1)
    for j = 1:size(B,2)
        tempy = squeeze(B(i,j,:));
        tempy2 = reshape(tempy, [84 84]);
        feats{end+1} = block_dct2(tempy2); %calculates dct2 for the block and returns a 1*200 vector

    end
end
```

Comment: The '4 corner blocks' is a red herring. If your callback function returned a 1x200 for each pixel in a 3x3 image - imagine each pixel being replaced by that 1x200 vector (resulting in a 200*3 wide image). You could 'reshape' the result if you know the output size of the callback function. Or, see if my answer helps you with an alternate approach.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29132803/3293881) helps?

Comment: Clarifying my first comment - This assumption: "Apparently, blockproc further divides the blocks into upper left, upper right, lower left and lower right and concatenates that result. And that is why I am getting all this mixed outputs." is incorrect. BLOCKPROC doesn't subdivide a given block size and the output is not mixed :) (I can explain in more detail, but I dont think that adds to this question)

Comment: Thank you @Divakar for the alternative solution. I will definitely look into it if this one fails :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe reshape you data in the third dimension?

```
>> A = magic(3)

A =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> B = blockproc(A, [1 1], @(x)reshape(x.data(:),[1 1 numel(x.data)]), 'BorderSize', [1 1], 'TrimBorder', false, 'PadPartialBlocks', true);

>> whos B
  Name      Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

  B         3x3x9              648  double  
>> squeeze(B(1,1,:))

ans =

     0
     0
     0
     0
     8
     3
     0
     1
     5

>>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question. And thank you for your answer. Can you please help me understand your code a little bit. When I applied your code to my image I got size ``2x17x24336``. I know that ``24336`` is because of my block size which is ``[156 156]`` but how do I interpret the other dimensions, does 17 mean I have 17 blocks? I need to get the rows back into matrix form to apply ``dct2`` to it, I tried ``reshape((squeeze(B(1,1,:))), [156 156])`` to get the first block, how do I get the other blocks? Thank you

Comment: Right I created a nested for loop and apparently the image is divided into ``17*2`` blocks and each can be obtained using the code above. I think this will work and I will give it a try. Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: @FarazKhan - Hard to follow what you are running into without some reproducible code. What is the next step? Why cant you fold that right into the blockproc callback itself (since in that context, you'll have the data as 156x156).

Comment: I added the code based on your answer to my main question, I just wanted a controllable way to divide the image into overlapping windows. Your code made it possible to control that. I tried adding the ``dct2`` call function in ``blockproc`` but that would again concatenate the results in a way that could not be used in my classifer as explained in my question above. What do you mean by ``blockproc`` returning data as ``156 x 156``? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An alternate using MAT2CELL:

```
function extractFeatures
images_m{1} = rand(128);
B = blockproc(images_m{1}, [64 64], @processBlock,...
    'BorderSize', [10 10], 'TrimBorder', false,...
    'PadPartialBlocks', true, 'PadMethod', 'replicate');

%B is 2x400 i.e 2x2 blocks of each block being a 1x200 feature vector
m = ones(1,size(B,1));
n = 200*ones(1,size(B,2)/200);
% The MAT2CELL help does a good job, just read it carefully and run the
% examples
feats = mat2cell(B,m,n);
feats = feats(:);

end

function feature = processBlock(bstruct)    
    % I dont know what block_dct2 does:
    %feature = block_dct2(bstruct.data);
    % So I'll put in a place holder which returns a 1x200 'feature'
    % for each overlapping image block
    feature = repmat(mean(bstruct.data(:)), [1 200]);
end
```

Comment: Many thanks @Ashish Uthama but I think I will go with the previous answer even though it appears more inefficient. It gives me more control over my results which I would like to have. This does not always work because based on my sliding window size I dont always get ``2*400`` ``B``. It varies with the block size. If I use a ``[16 16]`` window size the results returned by ``B`` are very different :(