# Is there a more efficient way to to divide my image into overlapping blocks?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to divide my image into overlapping blocks and process those blocks individually and store the output of each matrix into a matrix.

I have tried using `im2col` but it is not at all practical. My code is:

```
kek = im2col(images_m{1}, [64 64], 'sliding');
for i = 1: size(kek, 2)
    new = reshape(kek(:,i), [64 64]);
    %Extract features from the new block and save it in a concatenating
    %matrix
end
```

There are two problems with this, first there is no way to control the overlapping of blocks.

Second the process is very slow and very very memory hungry. I basically ran out of memory on my computer on the third image, even if I `clear` the previous images.

is there any efficient way to divide my images into overlapping blocks?

P.S. I cannot create a for image for every image as every image is of varying size :(

Comment: Look into [Efficient Implementation of `im2col` and `col2im`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25454746/3293881) if it helps. Also, what sizes of images are you dealing with? Basically, that neighborhood matrix with `im2col` is huge in itself, so it would make more sense to perform the extraction of features locally and then saving rather than creating the neighborhood matrix and then processing for feature extraction.

Comment: @Divakar Thank you, but the question you linked to is the implementation of ``im2col``, I already have the image processing toolbox, also if I am to use that function, how would I control the ``sliding`` overlap window? I agree with you regarding this being very inefficient. But I am trying to find alternatives here. ``blockproc`` would be ideal here but the problem is with output of ``blockproc`` which this question explains my problem exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109241/is-there-any-way-to-control-the-concatenation-of-the-blockproc-output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listed next is one approach to achieve [`im2col`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) with additional `overlapping` capability. It's built upon another Stackoverflow answer on [`Efficient Implementation of`im2col`and`col2im`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25454746/3293881). Here's the implementation -

```
function out = im2col_sliding_overlap(A,blocksize,overlap)

%// Get size of A for later usages
[M,N] = size(A);

%// Number of blocks to be formed along X-Y directions
num_blks_x = (M - overlap)/(blocksize(1)-overlap);
num_blks_y = (N - overlap)/(blocksize(2)-overlap);

%// Store blocksize as number of rows and columns information
nrows_blk = blocksize(1);
ncols_blk = blocksize(2);

%// Start indices for each block
start_ind = bsxfun(@plus,[0:num_blks_x-1]'*(nrows_blk-overlap)+1,...
                       [0:num_blks_y-1]*(ncols_blk - overlap)*M); %//'

%// Block offset indices
blkoffset_idx = bsxfun(@plus,[0:nrows_blk-1]',[0:ncols_blk-1]*M); %//'

%// Indices for all blocks
idx = bsxfun(@plus,blkoffset_idx(:),start_ind(:).');              %//'

%// Index into A to have the final output
out = A(idx);

return;
```

---

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
    0.6293    0.3797    0.8972    0.4471    0.1332    0.7758
    0.0207    0.6994    0.8347    0.6550    0.7619    0.6992
    0.5167    0.0107    0.9401    0.4059    0.7560    0.3019
    0.9483    0.1728    0.0323    0.8118    0.5423    0.3186
    0.6692    0.7135    0.5497    0.5216    0.9695    0.3097
    0.8801    0.1210    0.0402    0.7342    0.1006    0.4542

>> out = im2col_sliding_overlap(A,[4 4],2) %// Blocksize=[4 4], Overlap =2
out =
    0.6293    0.5167    0.8972    0.9401
    0.0207    0.9483    0.8347    0.0323
    0.5167    0.6692    0.9401    0.5497
    0.9483    0.8801    0.0323    0.0402
    0.3797    0.0107    0.4471    0.4059
    0.6994    0.1728    0.6550    0.8118
    0.0107    0.7135    0.4059    0.5216
    0.1728    0.1210    0.8118    0.7342
    0.8972    0.9401    0.1332    0.7560
    0.8347    0.0323    0.7619    0.5423
    0.9401    0.5497    0.7560    0.9695
    0.0323    0.0402    0.5423    0.1006
    0.4471    0.4059    0.7758    0.3019
    0.6550    0.8118    0.6992    0.3186
    0.4059    0.5216    0.3019    0.3097
    0.8118    0.7342    0.3186    0.4542
```

Comment: Thank you, thats perfect. I'll apply it and see how it goes

Comment: @ipunished I would be interested in learning about the efficiency of this code on your data too!